# SAS: Leading zeros and substituting negative values for alphabets in a number

Tags: debugging, sas

I have a column that has numbers with leading zeros. Some numbers have alphabet at the end like (00054A) denoting a particular value. I need to remove the leading zeros and substitute the alphabet with the value. Some alphabets have negative value and when I use functions (TRANSTRN/TRANWRD) to replace, only the hyphen gets replaced and the value looks like (000123-). I want this negative sign to be at the front of the number after the leading zeros are removed. Since there are alphabets with value (-12 to +12) on 6-8 different columns that need replacement, it would be better if its written in a macro? What function should I use to remove leading zeros and substitute the negative values in place of alphabet?

Data:

```
0830 4368 0000856A

0177 7520 0001299K
```

Code:

```
    data text1;
    infile "/location/file.txt";
    input VariableX $1-4 VariableY $5-8 VariableC $9-16
    run;    

    data text2;
    set text1;
    VariableC=TRANWRD(VariableC, 'A', '1'); 
    VariableC=TRANWRD(VariableC, 'K', '-2');
    run;
```

Output:

```
   0830 4368 00008561
   0177 7520 0001299-
```

Expected output:

```
   0830 4368 8561
   0177 7520 -12992
```

Comment: Please some some sample data, input and output and what you have attempted.

Comment: Have edited the post. Please check the code and outputs. Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you're inputting your data correctly?  Those look like they could be encoded in a particular format, you may be better off looking for an INFORMAT that could read them correctly without your calculations required.

Comment: A good list of informats is here, though it's a few versions out of date:http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a001239776.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If A and K are the only scenario you need to take care, then PRX function can deliver it by old school terms (if... then):

```
/* dummy dataset */
data have;
    input x $ y $ c$ :15.;
    datalines;
0830 4368 0000856A
0177 7520 0001299K
;
run;

data want;
    set have;

    if strip(reverse(c)) =:'A' then
        do;
            c=prxchange('s/A$/1/',-1, trim(c)); /*if the last char is A, first replace A with 1*/
            c=prxchange('s/^0*//',-1, trim(c)); /* Second replace the leading 0s with nothing*/
        end;
    else if strip(reverse(c)) =:'K' then
        do;
            c=prxchange('s/K$/2/',-1, trim(c)); /*If the last char is K, first replace K with 2*/
            c=prxchange('s/^0*/-/',-1, trim(c)); /*second replace the leading 0s with -*/
        end;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   data test;
   input VariableC $ 10.;
   posit =0;
   if substr(VariableC,2,2) = "00" then do;  <== not to process value with less than two trailing zero 
      x =1 ;
      do while (x ^=0 );
         posit +1;
         x=find(VariableC,"0", posit );  <== find where is the last zero.
         if ( x - posit  ) > 1 then x =0; <== Avoid finding '0' between non-zero number 
                                             and the end of expression
      end;

   subNewVariableC = substr(VariableC, posit   );
   end;

   if find( subNewVariableC, "A", -1 ) = 1 then 
      NewVariableC=TRANWRD( subNewVariableC, 'A', '1'); 

   if find(subNewVariableC, "K",-1) = 1 then do;
      NewVariableC=TRANWRD( subNewVariableC, 'K', '2');
      NewVariableC = trim("-") !! trim(NewVariableC); 
   end;   
   drop posit x subNewVariableC VariableC;    
   datalines;
   ...
   run;
```

It would do what you are expecting.

Meanwhile I am looking for good solutions so that I could learn as well...

Answer (score 0):

My preference would be to store the values of each letter in a format (actually an informat as it makes the code easier, but the principle is the same).  This is then used as a lookup to convert the letter to a number.

I've combined multiple functions into a single line, which makes it very long, the logic of this is as follows

- Extract the number part
- Extract the letter, convert to the required number (without the sign) and append to the number part already extracted
- Convert to number type using the `input` function
- Multiply the newly created number by the sign of the letter lookup value.  The `sign` function returns -1 for negative values, 1 for positive values and 0 for zero. To avoid multiplying by 0, I've added in a piece to make this 1.
- Convert this number back to a character value and left align to remove leading spaces

Hope this makes sense, here's the code.

```
/* create lookup informat */
proc format;
    invalue  letter 'A' = 1
                    'K' = -2;
run;

/* dummy dataset */
data have;
input x $ y $ c$ :15.;
datalines;
0830 4368 0000856A
0177 7520 0001299K
;
run;

/* transformed values */
data want;
set have;
c1 = left(put(input(
                    cats( compress(c,,'kd'), /* keep numbers */
                          abs(input(compress(c,,'ka'),letter.))) /* keep letter, convert to number (without the sign) and append to numbers */ 
              ,best12.)
                    *ifn(input(compress(c,,'ka'),letter.)=0,1,sign(input(compress(c,,'ka'),letter.))) /* multiply by sign of letter lookup number (if 0 then multiply by 1) */
         ,best12.));
run;
```

Comment: Say if there is a symbol that needs to be replaced with the value '0' ($ =0) then how to include that in input statement?

Comment: Just add it to the `proc format` statement ('$' = 0).  You will also need to change the second `compress` function to `abs(input(compress(c,,'d'),letter.)))` , this will remove all numbers, so will keep any letters or other characters.